# When does Wordpress execute the code in search.php

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I don't really understand how Wordpress' search works.  My ultimate problem is that I have search results showing in `search.php` via running through a loop and `$wp_query->the_post()`, but it only runs this code on the home page. at `'/'`.  I need it to show the search results on a page such as `'/search'` so that the search url appears in analytics.

**Is `search.php` only evaluated if we are on the page `'/'` and there is a parameter `?s=terms`**

How can I get this to run on another page? (I couldn't find an import for `search.php` like you can for `searchform.php` with `get_search_form()`)

I have a template (`search-page.php`) for a search page created per https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page but that page looks like it wants your search page to show a form, and then for search results it will send you to the home page.

**Am I just going to have to move all of my search results code to `search-page.php`?**

**Will Wordpress' default search query run on `search-page.php` with the `?s=` param if I do move all the code?**

I have tried putting search results code in a separate template file, but I'm not sure if I did it wrong or if you just can't get Wordpress' internal search to fire off of the `?s=` parameter when you aren't on the homepage.

Here's some strange behavior I don't understand:

I found this .htaccess rewrite rule and created one for me based on this page: http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/

Mine is currently:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,R,L]
```

now, when searching through `searchform.php` (which sends the text in the input to `'/'`) I get the `url: /search/?s=test`

This is the url I want, but the page that is served is as if Wordpress has performed a search and returned the top result and just shows me that instead.

If I use the rewrite from that page:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

I get a blank page (default template) `url: /search/term/`

and if I use this modified version:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,R,L]
```

I get my search results from `search.php` `url: /search/term/?s=term`

I dunno, maybe this is just my instance, but this seems like really bizarre behavior and I don't think I'm affecting this with any hooks or filters.

Comment: I presume you already have permalinks set to Post Name?

Comment: yes, it is set to post name.